# Loading angular directives at runtime

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive

I have a service that I call during `app.run()` and for some reason when I load the files async at that point they don't seem to take.

Here's the service i'm using:

```
angular.module('nav').service('SubmoduleService', ['submodules_config', 
    function(config){
        this.autoload = function(){
            for(var key in config.modules){
                    for(var i=0; i<config.modules[key].length; i++){
                            var src = config.modules[key][i].replace(':path', config.path).replace(':name', key);
                            console.log(src);
                            var js = document.createElement("script");

                            js.type = "text/javascript";
                            js.src = src;

                            document.body.appendChild(js);
                    }
            }

            return true;

    };
}]);
```

Here's the config file:

```
angular.module('nav').constant('submodules_config', {
    path: "scripts/submodules/:name",
    modules: {
            gallery: [':path/config.js', ':path/directive.js']
    }
});
```

So basically the config defines a module and all the files that need to get loaded for that module.

I see the files get loaded into the DOM, but for some reason when I load the controller that uses that directive, it doesn't work.

NOTE: The directive works when loading the files explicitly.

Any help is appreciated.

E

Answer (score 0):

By default, angular bootstraps the application on the DOM Ready event.  When you load scripts asynchronously, this event can be fired before the scripts load, so angular won't know about the directives contained in them when the DOM is $compiled().

There are quite a few ways to work around this, but they all revolve around deferring compilation of the DOM until the required modules are loaded.

On simple (but not the only) way to defer compilation for a fragment of your application is to simply use ng-if.  In pseudo code, it would look something like this:

```
<div ng-if="moduleWithMyDirectiveLoaded" my-directive></div>
```

This leaves you with the task of figuring out how to determine if a particular script has been loaded and getting that information into your angular application.

Unfortunately, this isn't trivial.  You can write this yourself, but others have already done it for you and you'd probably be better off using one of those tested, cross-browser solutions.

[require.js](http://requirejs.org) comes to mind as an option, but there are many others that would also work.

Comment: I'm well versed in require. I just don't like having to use the closure system around all of my files. I'm just looking for an easy way to optionally load modules at bootstrap time.